# М'який звук Л у слові "кольд/колд-крем"

Tags: іншомовні-слова

Як краще вживати назву косметичного засобу - колд крем чи кольд крем?

- > Вперше **колд-крем** з'явився досить давно. Ще в другому столітті один
  >   грецький доктор створив унікальну суміш, яка складалася з білого
  >   воску, рожевої води, а також оливкової і рожевого масла. Ефект цього
  >   засобу вразив публіку, тому так званий "Віск Галена" активно
  >   проводився протягом кількох століть.
  >
  > <sub>Джерело: http://lakomka.com.ua/news/6933/</sub>
- > найбільш демократичним та мінімальним виявився **кольдкрем** для дітей
  >   від Урьяж Uriage cold cream
  >
  > <sub>Джерело: https://www.instagram.com/p/BcfkkctB-A2/</sub>

На це питання Правопис каже:

> [§ 86](http://www.pravopys.net/#search=86-89). L
>
> 1. L у словах іншомовного походження передається твердим або м’яким л — залежно від того, як узвичаєне те чи інше слово в українській мові

Чи є міркування, як узвичаєне це слово в українській мові?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Коли бачите в правописі штибу «узвичаєне», то можна сміливо дивити словники чи навіть московську, бо саме багато під цӥм виразом приховано позначають прямі московізми.

Щодо словників, то *разом* і з, як типово для і московської, з *мняким **л***. Наприклад СУМ 20:

> [КОЛЬДКРЕ́М](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=43089&page=1359), *у*, *ч*.
>   Косметичний захисний і живильний крем на основі жирів і воску. *На носі він вгледів прищик, дістав з несесера кольдкрему, помазав й припудрив* (М. Коцюбинський); *Свою назву кольдкрем отримав через відчуття прохолоди, яке він викликає* (із журн.); *Кольдкрем має одну з найдовших історій у світі косметики* (із журн.).

За звучнею, звісно, правильно буде *колд* від очевидного анґліјського [*cold*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cold). Питанє про разом чи окремо — вже инше русло.

Comment: Я б не сказав, що для російської характерне м'яке _л_. Мені здається, в цьому слові в нас, навпаки, (через старий прецедент від Коцюбинського) пишеться/вимовляється «протилежно» російській. Але можливо, це ненадовго (і навіть не через вплив російської, а через вплив англійської).

Comment: @Sasha Характерно, але не скільки до загального запозиченьа, а саме від Анґліјськојі: Уел**ь**с… (до речи, одна з хвороб також писати через *у*, а не *в*) — і ја поки не знају чому. Хоча ја не заперечују, шчо украјинська подекуди сама маје мньакого **л**, але сье: 1) переважно дльа загальних запозичень; 2) через иншого сусьіда — польаків, котрі мајже завше пишуть через _ль_ /l/ через својејі особливостьи мови.

Answer (score 2):

Як не дивно, [«Словник укр. мови» в 20 томах](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=43089&page=1359) і [«Словники України on-line» від УМІФ](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/) наводять варіант **кольдкре́м**.

Comment: Написали раньіше, хех. До речи, цьікаво, шчо при цьому СУМ 11 вказује цього слова јак _застаріле_.